# How to make a conditional link-to in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, conditional-statements, link-to

I am using Ember.js version 2.8.2.

I want to wrap things inside `link-to` only if condition is true.

**First try**:

```
{{#if isAdmin}}
  {{#link-to admin}}
    contents here
  {{/link-to}}
  {{else}}
    contents here
{{/if}}
```

**Problem**: the code is not dry, because content repeats twice.

How should I do this? Thanks.

Comment: For me your code looks ok, since there is no condition check provided in link-to helper

Comment: @kumkanillam The code works, but it does not dry. In fact my contents has many lines, doing copy and paste like this is matainable. I am thinking a better way to do this.

Comment: then is it possible for you to create component and include that, so that you can write it in one place and use it every where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First option:**

If you want to remove it from your dom, wrap your "link-to" component as a component (my-admin-link.hbs):

```
{{#if isAdmin}}
  {{#link-to admin}}
    {{yield}}
  {{/link-to}}
{{else}}
    {{yield}}
{{/if}}
```

Than use it as:

```
{{#my-admin-link}}
   your content
{{/my-admin-link}}
```

**Second option:**

Use disabled and disabledClass of link-to:

```
{{#link-to admin disabled=isNotAdmin disabledClass='showastext'}}
    your content
{{/link-to}}
```

In your app.css showastext can be defined as:

```
.showastext{
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: text;
    color: black;
}
```